# Partial class specialization for function pointer type and value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, template-meta-programming

I'm using FLTK to do my GUI related stuff, and it requires functions of type `void (*fn)( Fl_Widget*, void* )` to be registered as widget callbacks. I'm tired of creating function forwarders by hand that unpack the `void*`s into parameters and call appropriate static functions from my classes to do the work the user has requested.

I came up with a solution, but it requires a class to be specialized for both function type, and function address, and this is where I'm having problems. Here's some code:

```
template< typename T, typename fn_ptr_t, fn_ptr_t fn_ptr >
struct Fl_Callback_package;

template< typename T, typename Return, typename... Params >
struct Fl_Callback_package< T, Return (*)( Params... ), /* What goes here? */ >
{
  //...
};
```

EDIT:
To clarify - I don't want a specific function in place of `/* What goes here? */`, but rather I would like this parameter to be `Return (*fn_ptr)( Params... )`. When I try

```
template< typename T, typename Return, typename... Params >
struct Fl_Callback_package< T, Return (*)( Params... ), Return (*fn_ptr)( Params... ) >
```

I get an error from GCC 4.8.1 saying that `fn_ptr`was not declared in this scope.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: The question is in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put `Return (*fn_ptr)( Params... )` in the wrong place. It's a template parameter of the partial specialization, so it goes into the `template <...>`.

```
template< typename T, typename fn_ptr_t, fn_ptr_t fn_ptr >
struct Fl_Callback_package;

template< typename T, typename Return, typename... Params, Return (*fn_ptr)( Params... ) >
struct Fl_Callback_package< T, Return (*)( Params... ), fn_ptr >
{
  //...
};
```

Comment: T.C. never fails to deliver. Thanks!