# How to Deduce Argument List from Function Pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Given two or more example functions, is it possible to write templated code which would be able to deduce the arguments of a function provided as a template parameter?

This is the motivating example:

```
void do_something(int value, double amount) {
    std::cout << (value * amount) << std::endl;
}

void do_something_else(std::string const& first, double & second, int third) {
    for(char c : first) 
        if(third / c == 0) 
            second += 13.7;
}

template<void(*Func)(/*???*/)>
struct wrapper {
    using Args = /*???*/;
    void operator()(Args&& ... args) const {
        Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    wrapper<do_something> obj; //Should be able to deduce Args to be [int, double]
    obj(5, 17.4); //Would call do_something(5, 17.4);
    wrapper<do_something_else> obj2; //Should be able to deduce Args to be [std::string const&, double&, int]
    double value = 5;
    obj2("Hello there!", value, 70); //Would call do_something_else("Hello there!", value, 70);
}
```

In both uses of `/*???*/`, I am trying to work out what I could put there that would enable this kind of code.

The following doesn't appear to work, due to `Args` not being defined before its first use (along with what I have to assume are numerous syntax errors besides), and even if it did, I'm still looking for a version that doesn't require explicit writing of the types themselves:

```
template<void(*Func)(Args ...), typename ... Args)
struct wrapper {
    void operator()(Args ...args) const {
        Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

wrapper<do_something, int, double> obj;
```

Comment: you mean [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) ?

Comment: @bolov What I'm looking for specifically is a way to deduce `Args` from the `Function` provided. `std::function` matches function pointers by having those types specified explicitly in the type parameter list.

Comment: do you accept C++17? wink wink

Comment: @bolov I'm using MSVC, so my ability to use C++17 is constrained by the quality of Microsoft's compiler implementation, but if an exclusively-C++17 solution exists, I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: May I ask what would be the benefits of having such wrappers when you can call `do_something` or `do_something_else` directly? Storing pointer to function as template parameter does not seem to be useful. Also if you don't want to write types you can utilize `decltype` to declare a first template parameter as pointer to method and then just pass pointer value as second parameter.

Comment: @VTT The use-case is a series of resource wrappers that use function pointers as part of their Destructors. It's too complicated on its own to bother demonstrating here, so I'm just showing the important part.

Comment: So you basically want to generate custom deleter template be used with `unique_ptr` or something similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With C++17 we can have auto template non-type parameters which make possible the `Wrapper<do_something> w{}` syntax <sup>1)</sup>.

As for deducing `Args...` you can do that with a [specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793151/2805305).

```
template <auto* F>
struct Wrapper {};

template <class Ret, class... Args, auto (*F)(Args...) -> Ret>
struct Wrapper<F>
{
    auto operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        return F(args...);
    }
};
```

```
Wrapper<do_something> w{};
w(10, 11.11);
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Without C++17 it's impossible to have the `Wrapper<do_something> w{}` nice syntax.

The best you can do is:

```
template <class F, F* func>
struct Wrapper {};

template <class Ret, class... Args, auto (*F)(Args...) -> Ret>
struct Wrapper<Ret (Args...), F>
{
    auto operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        return F(args...);
    }
};
```

```
Wrapper<declype(do_something), do_something> w{};
```

Comment: @Xirema C++17 is in the early stages of implementation. clang can compile it without a problem: https://godbolt.org/g/DyArxa

Answer (score 5):

With C++17, you can do this:

```
template <auto FUNC, typename = decltype(FUNC)>
struct wrapper;

template <auto FUNC, typename RETURN, typename ...ARGS>
struct wrapper<FUNC, RETURN (*)(ARGS...)> {
    RETURN operator()(ARGS ...args) {
        return FUNC(args...);
    }
};
```

I've learned this technique from W.F.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406009/8157187)

Comment: Bolov fixed his solution, and actually I like that solution better now.

Answer (score 3):

Further improvement of C++17 version: less template parameters and proper noexcept annotation:

```
template<auto VFnPtr> struct
wrapper;

template<typename TResult, typename... TArgs, TResult ( * VFnPtr)(TArgs...)> struct
wrapper<VFnPtr>
{
    TResult
    operator ()(TArgs... args) const noexcept(noexcept((*VFnPtr)(::std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)))
    {
        return (*VFnPtr)(::std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 you can consider a templated `make_wrapper` helper function. However, with this approach the function pointer is not a template parameter. Instead, the function pointer is "carried" by the non-static data member called `f_` in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

void do_something(int value, double amount) {
  std::cout << (value * amount) << std::endl;
}

void do_something_else(std::string const& first, double & second, int third) {
  for(char c : first)
    if(third / c == 0)
      second += 13.7;
}

template<class Ret, class... Args>
using function_pointer = Ret(*)(Args...);

template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct wrapper {
  using F = function_pointer<Ret, Args...>;

  F f_;

  explicit constexpr wrapper(F f) noexcept : f_{f} {}

  template<class... PreciseArgs>// not sure if this is required
  Ret operator()(PreciseArgs&&... precise_args) const {
    return f_(std::forward<PreciseArgs>(precise_args)...);
  }
};

template<class Ret, class... Args>
constexpr auto make_wrapper(
  function_pointer<Ret, Args...> f
) -> wrapper<Ret, Args...> {
  return wrapper<Ret, Args...>(f);
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto obj = make_wrapper(do_something);
  obj(5, 17.4);
  constexpr auto obj2 = make_wrapper(do_something_else);
  double value = 5;
  obj2("Hello there!", value, 70);

  return 0;
}
```