# Is there any good way to obtain the arg type list form function pointer in modern c++?

Tags: c++, c++17, function-pointers, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Say I have function pointer `R(*fp)(...A)`. Is there any way to get the type `R` and type list `A...`? `std::invoke_result_t` doesn't seem to work. And I cannot find anything for the argument list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>
typedef int(*fp_t)(int, float);
std::invoke_result_t<fp_t> x = 10;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

compile with c++17 gives error:

```
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/10.0.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> using invoke_result_t = typename std::invoke_result::type [with _Fn = int (*)(int, float); _Args = {}]':
prog.cc:6:26:   required from here
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/10.0.0/type_traits:2917:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<int (*)(int, float)>'
 2917 |     using invoke_result_t = typename invoke_result<_Fn, _Args...>::type;
```

Comment: Doesnt decltype((*fp_t)(0, 0.0)) work?

Comment: `std::invoke_result_t<fp_t>` -> `std::invoke_result_t<fp_t, int, float>`.

Comment: yes, the invoke_result_t needs the arg list, which I do not want to give manually.

Comment: How do you want to get it?  There are plenty of ways, but they differ in how A... is delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but seems to me you're looking for the `std::function` deduction guides (introduced in C++17).

With

```
using fnT = decltype(std::function{std::declval<fp_t>()});
```

you obtain a `std::function<int(int, float)>`.

Adding the following custom type trait

```
template <typename>
struct toTuple;

template <typename R, typename ... As>
struct toTuple<std::function<R(As...)>>
 {
   using retType  = R;
   using argTypes = std::tuple<As...>;
 };
```

you can obtain the return type

```
using rT  = typename toTuple<fnT>::retType;
```

or a `std::tuple` with the arguments

```
using asT = typename toTuple<fnT>::argTypes;
```

Using `std::tuple_element_t` you can extract the single argument type.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

typedef int(*fp_t)(int, float);

template <typename>
struct toTuple;

template <typename R, typename ... As>
struct toTuple<std::function<R(As...)>>
 {
   using retType  = R;
   using argTypes = std::tuple<As...>;
 };


int main()
 {
   using fnT = decltype(std::function{std::declval<fp_t>()});
   using rT  = typename toTuple<fnT>::retType;
   using asT = typename toTuple<fnT>::argTypes;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<fnT, std::function<int(int, float)>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<rT, int> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<0u, asT>, int> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<1u, asT>, float> );
 }
```

Comment: You don't need `std::function` if you're going to do use a type trait anyway. `fp_t` is an `R(*)(Args...)`, the `function` doesn't give you anything extra.

Comment: @Barry - `std::function` deduction guides are more flexible than a single custom type trait: this solution works also with function types, lambdas, `std::bind` results.

Comment: Hmm, it does look a bit roundabout at first sight, but piggybacking onto `std::function`'s copious deduction capabilities is quite clever indeed.

Comment: please noticed. The libc++ still does not have deduction guides yet. Only libstdc++ has it.

Answer (score 5):

Deducing them with a template metafunction:

```
#include <tuple>
typedef int(*fp_t)(int, float);

template <class T>
struct function_signature{};

template <class Return, class... Args>
struct function_signature<Return(*)(Args...)> {
    using return_type = Return;
    using args = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

int main()
{
    using ret = function_signature<fp_t>::return_type;
    using args = function_signature<fp_t>::args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
std::invoke_result_t<fp_t>
```

to:

```
std::invoke_result_t<fp_t, int, float> x = 10;
```

since you also need the types of the parameters of the method, as @Fureeish commented and confirmed in the [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Use Clang to compile it (as suggested in [How to Deduce Argument List from Function Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533698/how-to-deduce-argument-list-from-function-pointer)) and see the <kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uQRFZCUzRJn7pzQl)</kbd>.

Comment: the tech you refer to is to deduct from a non-type template value. But fp_t is a type and I do not want to manually and the arg list.