# Deducing parameter list of a member function

Tags: templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

We want to be able to deduce the argument list of a member function call in a template. This is part of a larger project that performs ultimately a type conversion that allows a target function to be called.

Our research resulted in [How to Deduce Argument List from Function Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533698/how-to-deduce-argument-list-from-function-pointer) and that helped a lot.

We are now stuck at finding a similar concept for member functions.  The key elements are in the following Source 1 code example:

- In main, comment `// Free funct.` : This demonstrates the successful case for free functions, and shows for free functions what we want to achieve for member functions.
- In main, comment `Extrinsic call to member function.` and `Problem 1`.  This drafts the target syntax we try to support for extrinsic calls to member functions.
- In `object::exec(...)` : This drafts the target syntax for the call from inside the object.

See the second code block that demonstrates our current research:  We know the difference between a function and a member pointer and that a calling a member requires an object identity.  But we are not able to express our knowledge in code. The second code block does not compile.

What is the correct notation and template deduction structure to achive the shown notation?

### Source 1

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void free_funct(int p1, double p2) {
    std::cout << "p1=" << p1 << " p2=" << p2 << endl;
}

struct object {
    void object_funct(double p1, int p2) const {
        std::cout << "p1=" << p1 << " p2=" << p2 << endl;
    }
    int exec(double p1, int p2) {
        // Ultimate goal:
        // Wrapper<(???::object_funct> functor3;
        // functor_3(p1, p2;)
    }
};

template <auto F>
class Wrapper {};

template <typename R, typename... Args, auto (F)(Args...)->R>
struct Wrapper<F>
{
    auto operator()(Args... args) const -> R {
        return F(args...);
    }
};

int main() {
    // Free funct.
    Wrapper<free_funct> functor1{};
    functor1(313, 3.141592);
    object object;
    // Extrinsic call to member function.
    object.object_funct(3.1415926, 313);
    // Problem 1:
    Wrapper<&object::object_funct> functor2;
    // How to express this below
    // functor2(3, 1415926, 313);
    object.exec(2.718281, 121);
    return 0;
}
```

## Source 2 (Does not compile)

```cpp
template <auto F>
struct Wrap;
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args, R(T::* F)(Args...)>
struct Wrap<F> {
    auto operator()(Args... args) {
        return F(args...);
    }
};

struct foo {
    int bar(float) { 
        return 1; };
};

int main() {
    foo x;
    Wrap<&x::bar> f;
    f(3.14159265);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't call a member function without an instance of the class. What instance is `f(3.14);` suppose to use here? There is no instance of `foo` in you code example.

Comment: `does not compile` why not? what error do you get? [edit] to quote it in full. I bet it's illuminating.

Comment: @super : Forgot the instance.  Edited, added the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now that you expect `Wrapper` to wrap a member function pointer by template parameter, you have to know **how member function pointer to be called**. usually we call a member function pointer using `(obj.*mfptr)(args...)` or `(optr->*mfptr)(args...)`, it's clearly that the object itself is also necessary for the call operation. so in the `Wrapper::operator()`, we need not only each of arguments, but also the object.

```cpp
template <auto F>
struct Wrapper;
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args, R(T::* F)(Args...)>
struct Wrapper<F> {
    // it seems you don't take care of the cvref qualifiers, so I won't write all the overloads.
    auto operator()(T obj, Args... args) {
        return (obj.*F)(args...);
    }
    auto operator()(T* obj, Args... args) {
        return (obj->*F)(args...);
    }
};
```

actually, a member function call is **similar** (not **equal**) to a function call which treat the object as the first argument. so you have to call it as following:

```cpp
Wrapper<&foo::bar> f;
f(foo{}, 3.14);
```

**EDIT:**
now that you want the instance to be wrapped as well, the `Wrapper` have to construct with the instance:

```cpp
template <auto F>
struct Wrapper;
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args, R(T::* F)(Args...)>
struct Wrapper<F> {
    // I also omit the overloads of pass by reference semantics.
    Wrapper(T obj) :instance(std::move(obj)){}

    auto operator()(Args... args) {
        return (instance.*F)(args...);
    }
private:
    T instance;
};

int main(){
    foo x;
    Wrapper<&foo::bar> f{x};
    f(3.14);
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants the Wrapper to remember the instance: `Wrapper<&foo::bar> f(x); f(3.14); /* acts like x.bar(3.14); */` - that's a small modification to your Wrap; it just needs to remember `x`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm not sure whether OP doesn't know a member function call needs the object itself, or he wants a function wrapper (even a function pointer) that performs as `obj.bar`. we can make `Wrapper` do like it, but also we can make `Wrapper` do like the one using function pointer. it depends on what OP really wants.

Comment: @RedFog & Raymond, the goal is to wrap also the instance.

Comment: Great.  Learned a lot!