# Is there a way to convert a function pointer to an std::function without specifying return type and argument type?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a function pointer that I need to pass to a function that expects a `std::function`. The function that takes the `std::function` is templated and uses the `std::function`'s arguments to deduce a parameter pack, meaning an implicit conversion won't work.

I could construct the `std::function` myself, but the function being passed has many arguments, and writing them into the template brackets of `std::function` will not be sustainable, as I need to do this often with many similar functions that I pass to this function.

Is there a way to convert a function pointer to a `std::function` without specifying the return type and arguments, by some form of deducing?

This is what I've tried so far:

```cpp
template <auto* F>
struct stdfunc {};

template <class Ret, class... Args, auto (*F)(Args...) -> Ret>
struct stdfunc<F>
{
    typedef std::function<Ret(Args...)> type;
};
```

The above code does not work as intended. I found the syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533854/13699024). In that case, it wasn't used for this purpose, but surely there is a way to achieve what I'm trying to do using this technique? It seems like all the pieces are there, I just have to put them in the right place.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
template<typename Func>
auto make_function(Func ptr)
{
    return std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<Func>>(ptr);
}
```

and then simply pass "make_function(my_func)".

(Thanks toRemy Lebeau for suggesting use of "auto")

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make the function return `auto`? `template<typename Func>
auto make_function(Func ptr) { return std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<Func>>(ptr); }`

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to check if `Func` is of function pointer type at compile time? Either with a `static_assert` or an `enable_if`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++17 or above, you could rely on class template argument deduction and simply declare

```
std::function fn_wrap{&fn};
```

where `fn` is the name of your function.