# C++ 20 lambda in template: unable to deduce ‘auto*’ from lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Given the following simple wrapper struct (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533854)):

```cpp
template <auto* F> struct Wrapper;

template <class Ret, class... Args, auto (*F)(Args...) -> Ret>
struct Wrapper<F>
{
    auto operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        return F(args...);
    }
};
```

The following works:

```cpp
int this_works(){
    return 42;
}
int main(){
    return Wrapper<this_works>()();
}
```

But I want this, using c++ 20:

```cpp
int main(){
    return Wrapper<[](){return 42;}>()();
}
```

`g++-11 --std=c++20` and `clang++13 --std=c++20` both complain about the latter
with some hard to decipher error messages, including:

- mismatched types ‘auto*’ and ‘main()::<lambda()>
- error: non-type template parameter 'F' with type 'auto *' has incompatible initializer

Is there a way to make the second example work? I tried a constexpr function
pointer to the lambda but it complained about it having no linkage ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wrapper` expects function pointer, but template argument deduction won't consider implicit conversion (from lambda without capture to function pointer).

You can convert the lambda to function pointer explicitly:

```
int main(){
    return Wrapper<static_cast<int(*)()>([](){return 42;})>()();
}
```

or

```
int main(){
    return Wrapper<+[](){return 42;}>()();
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8Wyp9Nr5YTw8V0Nv)

Comment: this leads to the linkage error again (gcc:) ‘main()::<lambda()>::_FUN’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int (*)()’ because ‘static constexpr int main()::<lambda()>::_FUN()’ has no linkage

Comment: Your answer in and by itself is correct though, and clang 13 likes it. Should i edit the question or ask a new one?

Comment: @ChrisB If you have another question, then ask a new one.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!

Comment: For anybody having the same issue, the follow up question regarding gcc is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980245/compiler-difference-between-gcc-11-and-clang-13-constexpr-lambda-has-no-linkage]

Comment: @ChrisB: That’s a [longstanding GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258).